Smart cast fails after upgrade to Kotlin 2.0
I was using Kotlin 1.9.23 and the following code compiled without issue:
    var module: Module? = null
    for (line in lines) {
        if (line.startsWith("[")) {
            module = null

            val matcher = modulePattern.matcher(line)
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                module = Schema.modules[matcher.group(1)]
            }

            if (module == null) {
                LOG.warn { "Encountered unexpected module: $line. All subsequent values will be ignored." }
            }

            continue
        } else {
            val matcher = valuePattern.matcher(line)
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                if (module == null) {
                    LOG.warn { "Ignored property from unknown module: $line." }
                } else {
                    val tokens = matcher.group(1).split("\\.".toRegex(), 2)

                    val fieldName = tokens[0]
                    val mapKey = if (tokens.size == 2) tokens[1] else null

                    val field = Schema.fields.getValue(module)[fieldName]
                    if (field == null) {
                        LOG.warn { "Ignored unknown property \"${matcher.group(1)}\" from module ${module.name}." }
                        continue
                    }

                    val value: String = matcher.group(2)

                    if (field !is MapField) {
                        Model.setFieldValue(FieldValue(field, TypedValue.createValue(field.type, value)))
                    } else {
                        maps.computeIfAbsent(field) { arrayListOf() }.add("$mapKey=$value")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

After upgrading my project to use Kotlin 2.0, however, the following log statement is causing issues:
LOG.warn { "Ignored unknown property \"${matcher.group(1)}\" from module ${module.name}." }
I get the compiler error Smart cast to 'Module' is impossible, because 'module' is a local variable that is mutated in a capturing closure.
The issue however is that there are no additional threads running. The only two places where module is re-assigned to null is in the if block above.
Is this a bug in Kotlin 2.0 or is there something I'm not aware of? I'm very new to Kotlin.

Please reduce your code to a [mre]. Most of what you posted won't be necessary to reproduce the problem.

Generally speaking, you can get around these sorts of things with a call to ?.let { }. That might help you work around the error.

The compiler is right to prevent you from running the code. Depending on what LOG.warn does you could run into a race condition where module actually could be null and your program  will end up with a NullPointerException during runtime.
The problem is that you pass a lambda to LOG.warn, not a String. This lambda captures the variable module because you want to access its name property. The lambda is executed at some later time, at the leisure of LOG.warn. And only then module.name is accessed. It may even be executed concurrently(*), and in that case the rest of your program would have continued and it might have set module to null in the meantime. When the lambda now tries to access the name property it would throw a NullPointerException.
There are a lot of mays and mights and in practice this will probably never be a problem. But the bottom line is that the compiler can never actually be sure this is safe. That's why it forbids it in the first place. Well, apparently only the new K2 compiler does since the older compiler didn't complain. But that's only because the new compiler is smarter, the old compiler shouldn't have allowed that either.
What to do now? It all depends on what LOG.warn actually is. If you have control over its implementation you can change it

to take a String as a parameter instead of a () -> String
or make warn an inline function. That allows the compiler to see inside the funtion to determine if there are any shenanigans going on. If the lambda is not executed concurrently it will allow module.name to be accessed in the lambda.

If you cannot change LOG.warn then your options are to:

Access module.name outside the lambda by constructing the error message beforehand:
val message = "Ignored unknown property \"${matcher.group(1)}\" from module ${module.name}."
LOG.warn { message }


Raise an issue with the maintainer of LOG and ask them to fix this. It is not uncommon to use a logger the way you do, so you shouldn't be forced to use workarounds. Until they fixed the problem you would need to stay on the latest Kotlin 1.9.

Use another logger that doesn't exhibit this problematic behavior.



(*): Most loggers actually do run certain parts of the logging logic in a separate thread in order for the rest of the program not to be slowed down.
